# Displayport monitor in bootcamp not working

Tags: display, bootcamp, windows, displayport

I just installed windows 7 on my early macbook pro retina 15. Everything is working fine. I've also updated all my drivers, including graphic.

I have an extern monitor with a displayport.

It looks like the window does not even recognize my monitor.

Is there an extra step I need to do to enable a displayport monitor in bootcamp?

Comment: Windows 7 isn't supported on a '15 Mac - see https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204048

Comment: @Tetsujin // Thank you, but I see 'Windows 7' link on that page. Where does it say it does not support windows 7?

Comment: Moon, to clarify, do you own a 2015 MacBook, or a 15" MacBook? Or, do you own a 15" 2015 MacBook Pro?

Comment: @agentroadkill "my early macbook pro retina 15"